# CakePHP 2.3 Method onlyAllow does not exist

Tags: cakephp-2.3

Strange error tonight when attempting to delete a record:

```
Method onlyAllow does not exist

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

APP/Controller/VendorsController.php line 136 → CakeRequest->__call(string, array)
APP/Controller/VendorsController.php line 136 → CakeRequest->onlyAllow(string, string)
[internal function] → VendorsController->delete(string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 485 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(VendorsController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 186 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 161 → Dispatcher->_invoke(VendorsController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 92 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Can't figure out what is going on - the delete method is straight outta cake bake. My only guess is that permissions are too tight on the http document root but that seems like a stretch. No httpd errors. This happens both with admin prefix and without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this very same issue. After some digging I realized that I had changed my environment to use a more recent version of CakePHP (2.3.0). But, the project I was baking for was (2.2.3).  So, it looks like between Cake 2.2.x and 2.3.x they changed some things.

To fix my controllers that were baked with 2.3 in my 2.2.x project, I ended up removing this line from the delete function in my controller...

```
$this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
```

I then replaced that with the following at the very top of the function...

```
if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
}
```

NOTE: You can find what version of CakePHP your app is using by viewing the /lib/Cake/VERSION.txt file.

Comment: sorry I just noticed this (months later). I came to the same conclusion and forgot about this post...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Vendor is a reserved word. Renaming controller, model and views works fine.